# How to find nested string array element by length in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, multidimensional-array, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have highly unstructured dynamic data where I have a field that is a multidimensional string array. The exact size of the outer or inner arrays is not known beforehand and can vary. I would like to find all documents where any/all of the nested array elements evaluate on a condition I have. So for the example document below I only want to match it **if ANY of the arrays has elements that are ALL have a string length greater than 3** - which would be true in this case.

```json
{
  "_id": "00000000-0000-0007-0000-000000000001",
  "stringArrays": [
    [
      "Hello",
      "World",
      "!"
    ],
    [
      "Fred",
      "Todd"
    ]
  ]
}
```

The first array contains an element that is less than 3 the "!", but the second array with names matches both values of string length > 3. So overall the condition is met.

So far I have tried to find info about how to do this but all answers were either using fixed array indices which I can't or hard regex conditions which works better but will not work in all my cases. Sometimes I need to also query element.Length $IN [1,3,5,..] so exact string length values and not just $LT or $EQ or $GT.

My only lead is maybe using https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/#example somehow to project additional string length data to query later, but I would not know how to create a nested `stringArraysLengths` that maybe have the same structure but instead of values it has the string lengths I can query instead.

Maybe there are better ways to do this. I am relatively new to Mongodb and would appreciate some more experience users giving me a few hints to find the right way to do this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you could do it with nested `"$reduce"` operations.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$stringArrays",
          "initialValue": false,
          "in": {
            "$or": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$reduce": {
                  "input": "$$this",
                  "initialValue": {
                    "$gt": [{"$size": "$$this"}, 0]
                  },
                  "in": {
                    "$and": [
                      "$$value",
                      {"$gt": [{"$strLenCP": "$$this"}, 3]}
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hd6yfEz6m2y).

Answer (score 1):

This would be my approach:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         lengthArray: {
            $map: {
               input: "$stringArrays",
               as: "outer",
               in: {
                  $min: { // get the shortest length
                     $map: {
                        input: "$$outer",
                        in: { $strLenCP: "$$this" } // get length of each sub-strings
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         overall: { $max: "$lengthArray" }
      }
   },
   { $match: { overall: { $gt: 3 } } },
   //{ $unset: ["lengthArray", "overall"] }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/M7sQ7enfN2I)

Or use `$filter` to remove all short strings and check if result is not empty.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $set: {
         lengthArray: {
            $map: {
               input: "$stringArrays",
               as: "outer",
               in: {
                  $filter: {
                     input: "$$outer",
                     cond: { $gt: [{ $strLenCP: "$$this" }, 3] } // remove all short strings
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      $set: {
         lengthArray: {
            $filter: {
               input: "$lengthArray",
               cond: { $gt: [{ $size: "$$this" }, 0] } // remove all empty arrays
            }
         }
      }
   },
   { $match: { lengthArray: { $ne: [] } } },
   //{ $unset: "lengthArray" }
])
```